# Настройка index.html на весь экран

Tags: android-studio, meta

Сделал `index.html` 608x1080 для отображения в `WebView` (Android Studio).
В onCreate добавил:

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

В index.html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=1080, width=1920, user-scalable=no " />
```

Страница отображается как нужно в полный размер, но появился вертикальный скроллин. Как его убрать? Или есть другая комбинация для такого результата?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт. Нужно было в width указать 608...